# Булевы(логические) операции с моделями

Tags: unity3d

Существует необходимость во время выполнения выполнять булевы(логические) операции с 3d-объектами. Существует ли готовое решение? Unity 5.

P.S. Куда копать, если готовых решений не существует?

Comment: А можно поподробнее? Что за логические операции с объектами?

Comment: Видимо имеется в виду что-то такое: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/boolean-subtraction-operations-on-mesh.85713/